# mongodb / mongoose - join the results from one collection with results from another where their IDs match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongo and getting a bit tripped up with the variety of options for $lookup, aggregate, populate, etc. I want to make sure I'm using the best data structure.

I currently have two schemas - one for Urls that get saved, and another for Stats that should get associated with those Urls.

URL Schema:

```
const UrlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  urlId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
...
```

Stat Schema:

```
const StatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  urlRef: { //each urlRef corresponds to a `urlId` inside the UrlSchema
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
...
```

I was trying to just return results of all the urls and their corresponding stats in nodejs by looping through them and adding the stats, but I can tell this is not the appropriate way to do this:

```
//get the urls
const urls = await Url.find({ userId: userId })

//add the stats to each url
for (const url of urls) {
  const urlStats = await Stat.find({ urlRef: url.urlId });
  url.stats = urlStats || [];
}

//send the urls with their stats back to the client
res.json(urls);
```

what is the proper way to do this? The number of stats for each URL could potentially get very large, so I don't want to just store them as an array within each URL directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework with [`$lookup` stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the two collections based on the matching IDs.

Here is the query:

```js
db.urls.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: "123"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "stats",
      localField: "urlId",
      foreignField: "urlRef",
      as: "stats"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is a link to MongoDB playground where you can see your query work live: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WWQGgqbxLFH

Comment: This was great - for my specific implementation - I just needed to run that as: `const urls = await Url.aggregate([...]).exec();`